# Unicode characters (UTF-32) String encoding in NSRegularExpression

Tags: regex, swift, character-encoding, nsregularexpression, turtle-rdf

I'm writing a parser for RDF data in Turtle format in Swift. The Turtle Grammar defines the patter `PN_CHARS_BASE` as

```
[163s]  PN_CHARS_BASE ::= [A-Z] | [a-z] | [#x00C0-#x00D6] | [#x00D8-#x00F6] | [#x00F8-#x02FF] | [#x0370-#x037D] | [#x037F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
```

(see the [W3C Turtle recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#grammar-production-PN_CHARS_BASE)).

The last group in the pattern `[#x10000-#xEFFFF]` is outside the range of UTF-16 string encoding. UTF-32 is needed here.

This pattern is used to match, for instance, the first character in the prefix in a prefixed string such as `foaf` in `foaf:name`, numbers are not allowed here.

I would like to use `NSRegularExpression` for parsing turtle files. So to match the `PN_CHARS_BASE` pattern, I have the following code for testing:

```
    let PN_CHARS_BASE = "[A-Z]|[a-z]|[\\u00C0-\\u00D6]|[\\u00D8-\\u00F6]|[\\u00F8-\\u02FF]|[\\u0370-\\u037D]|[\\u037F-\\u1FFF]|[\\u200C-\\u200D]|[\\u2070-\\u218F]|[\\u2C00-\\u2FEF]|[\\u3001-\\uD7FF]|[\\uF900-\\uFDCF]|[\\uFDF0-\\uFFFD]|[\\u10000-\\uEFFFF]"
    do {
        let teststr = "9"
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: PN_CHARS_BASE, options: [])
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(teststr, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, teststr.characters.count)) as Array<NSTextCheckingResult>
    } catch {

    }
```

When I run this through the debugger, the regular expression returns one result on the test string `9`. But numbers are not allowed for this pattern (the regex should therefore return no matches). I removed parts of the regex pattern to determine which part of the regex matched the number `9` and found out that the last part of the regex `[\u10000-\uEFFFF]` matches with `9`. This is the only part of the pattern that is in UTF-32 and not in UTF-16 and includes characters such as Egyptian Hieroglyphs.

Do you know if `NSRegularExpression` is able to support UTF-32 characters?
Or of any other solution to support UTF-32 matching?

Answer (score 6):

I just found the answer myself. I needed to specify the UTF-32 characters in a different format than the UTF-16 characters.

Not `[\u10000-\uEFFFF]` but `[\U00010000-\U000EFFFF]` is needed to express the full range of unicode characters. The UTF-32 Unicode code point starts with an escaped CAPITAL `\U` and needs exactly 8 hex digits.